# The termination of an application started as a child process ends the calling application

Tags: c#

I have an application that launches another application from my project:

```
MainWindow mw = new OtherApplication.MainWindow();
mw.Show();
```

When this other application is closed, it also automatically terminates the parent application. This is what I try to avoid.
I use this method to close the child application:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

The subordinate application can either be used independently or it is called by the parent application. Can I somehow determine whether the application was started alone or whether it runs as a child process of the parent application? In this case, I would probably have to adjust the btnClose_Click method?

How can I close the appliactions running as a child process without terminating the parent application?

Comment: but application.current.shutdown is your main one..  if you close the window of the other app it will close the app

Comment: The child application was originally developed as a stand-alone application. I suspect that I have to make the termination in btnClose_Click dependent on whether the application was opened independently or started as a child process. I just do not know how I recognize that.

Answer (score 0):

I found out for myself:

```
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string processname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension 
                (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            if (processname != "OtherApplicationName")
                Close();
            else
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```